# Knockout - ko.computed with ko.isObservable and peek()

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a problem. Help me, please.
I have ko.computed which has a check ko.isObservable variable and I need that ko.computed not react to changes on this variable.
Please, see example:

```
ko.computed(function() {
      if ( ko.isObservable(test.peek()) ) {
        console.log('TRUE');
      }
});
```

------- OR --------

```
ko.computed(function() {
      if ( ko.isObservable(test).peek() ) {
        console.log('TRUE');
      }
});
```

I have error:
*Cannot read property 'peek' of null*

And if I do for example this:

```
 ko.computed(function() {
     var testTest = ko.isObservable(test) ? test.peek() : false;
          if ( testTest ) {
            console.log('TRUE');
          }
 });
```

ko.computed all the same be react to changes on 'test'.

How do that ko.computed not react to changes on this varible?

Comment: Why have you got a `computed` at all if you don't want to react to changes?  Just use a normal function?  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry me. I need the check ko.isObservable and use peek() that ko.computed not react when I change variable 'test', but I don't know, how use them together. 
Also if I use for example: ko.isObservable(test) ? test.peek() : false; ko.computed react if I change variable 'test'.
I need something like that ko.isObservable(test).peek(), but 'test' can be of null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recalculate computed on "test" value changes and don't know - whether "test" is observable or not:

```
ko.computed(function() {
      if ( ko.unwrap(test) ) {
        console.log('TRUE');
      }
});
```

Also I don't quite understand - why are you using peek() inside computed? This prevents computed from being recalculated on "test" value changes.

#### Update

I you want not to react on "test" value changes:

```
ko.computed(function() {
      var testValue = ko.isObservable(test) ? test.peek() : test;
      if ( testValue ) {
        console.log('TRUE');
      }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the value of the test variable and you don't know whether it is an observable or not, you can use ko.utils.unwrapObservable to just get the value. Like this:

```
ko.computed(function() {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(test);
});
```

In your example, you get the js error because you try to use peek() on the result of ko.isObservable(), which is either true for observables or null for everything else.